# I wrote a bootloader but it always jumps to the failure section I wrote and does not load my stage 2

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I wrote a bootloader which should load my KRNLDR.SYS on a FAT12 formatted img file. But it doesn't work

Commands I used to create it:

```
nasm -fbin -o boot.bin boot.asm
dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img bs=512 count=2880
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 test.img
sudo mkdosfs -F 12 /dev/loop0
```

Now my system recognizes and mounts the device and I put my KRNLDR.SYS on it

Then I executed:

```
sudo dd if=boot.bin of=/dev/loop0 bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
sudo umount /dev/loop0
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Now the file looks like a FAT12 floppy with a bootsector and the file KRNLDR.SYS

Now I execute it in QEMU:

```
qemu-system-i386 -device format=raw,file=test.img
```

And the output:

```
Operating System not found
Press any key to reboot
```

This is the output my bootloader prints to the screen if the file KRNLDR.SYS cannot be found by my bootloader

My Code:

```
org 0x0
bits 16

    jmp     word loader

bsOEMName:                  db "TestOS  "
bpbBytesPerSector:          dw 512
bpbSectorsPerCluster:       db 1
bpbReservedSectors:         dw 1
bpbNumberOfFATs:            db 2
bpbNumberOfRootEntries:     dw 224
bpbTotalSectors:            dw 2880
bpbMedia:                   db 0xf0
bpbSectorsPerFAT:           dw 9
bpbSectorsPerTrack:         dw 18
bpbNumberOfHeads:           dw 2
bpbHiddenSectors:           dd 0
bpbTotalSectorsBig:         dd 0
bsDriveNumber:              db 0
bsReserved:                 db 0
bsExtendedBootSignature:    db 0x29
bsVolumeID:                 dd 0x12345678
bsVolumeLabel:              db "TestOS     "
bsFileSystem:               db "FAT12   "

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; SI = Zero terminated string to print
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

printMsg:
    push    ax

.printStart:
    lodsb
    or      al, al
    jz      .printEnd

    mov     ah, 0x0e
    int     0x10
    jmp     .printStart

.printEnd:
    pop     ax

    ret

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; AX = Starting sector
; CX = Number of sectors to read
; ES:BX = Buffer
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

readSectors:
    mov     di, 0x0005

.readLoop:
    push    ax
    push    bx
    push    cx

    call    lbaToChs

    mov     ah, 0x02
    mov     al, 0x01
    mov     ch, byte [track]
    mov     cl, byte [sector]
    mov     dh, byte [head]
    mov     dl, byte [bsDriveNumber]
    int     0x13
    jnc     .success

    dec     di
    pop     cx
    pop     bx
    pop     ax
    jnz     .readLoop

.success:
    pop     cx
    pop     bx
    pop     ax

    inc     ax
    add     bx, word [bpbBytesPerSector]
    loop    readSectors

    ret

track:      db      0
head:       db      0
sector:     db      0

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; AX = Logical sector
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

lbaToChs:
    xor     dx, dx
    div     word [bpbSectorsPerTrack]
    inc     dl
    mov     byte [sector], dl

    xor     dx, dx
    div     word [bpbNumberOfHeads]
    mov     byte [head], dl
    mov     byte [track], al

    ret

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; AX = Cluster number
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

clusterToLba:
    sub     ax, 0x0002
    xor     cx, cx
    mov     cl, byte [bpbSectorsPerCluster]
    mul     cx

    ret

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

loader:
    cli

    mov     ax, 0x07c0
    mov     es, ax
    mov     gs, ax
    mov     fs, ax
    mov     ds, ax

    mov     ax, 0x0000
    mov     ss, ax
    mov     sp, 0xffff

    sti

    mov     byte [bsDriveNumber], dl

    xor     dx, dx
    xor     cx, cx
    mov     ax, 0x0020
    mul     word [bpbNumberOfRootEntries]
    div     word [bpbBytesPerSector]
    xchg    cx, ax ; Number of sectors of the root directory

    mov     al, byte [bpbNumberOfFATs]
    mul     word [bpbSectorsPerFAT]
    add     ax, word [bpbReservedSectors] ; Starting sector of the root directory

    mov     bx, 0x0200
    call    readSectors

    mov     cx, word [bpbNumberOfRootEntries]
    mov     di, 0x0200

searchRoot:
    push    cx
    mov     cx, 0x000b
    mov     si, stage2

    push    di
    rep cmpsb
    pop     di

    je      loadFat
    pop     cx
    add     di, 0x0020
    loop    searchRoot

    jmp     failure

loadFat:
    mov     dx, [di + 26] ; Starting address of entry
    xor     ax, ax
    mov     al, byte [bpbNumberOfFATs]
    mul     word [bpbSectorsPerFAT] ; Number of sectors used by the FATs

    mov     word [cluster], dx
    mov     cx, ax
    mov     ax, word [bpbReservedSectors]

    mov     bx, 0x0200
    call    readSectors

    mov     ax, 0x0050
    mov     es, ax
    mov     bx, 0x0000
    push    bx

loadFile:
    mov     ax, word [cluster]
    pop     bx
    call    clusterToLba
    xor     cx, cx
    mov     cl, byte [bpbSectorsPerCluster]
    call    readSectors
    push    bx

    mov     ax, word [cluster]

    mov     cx, ax
    mov     dx, ax
    shr     dx, 1
    add     cx, dx

    mov     bx, 0x0200
    add     bx, cx
    mov     dx, [bx]

    test    ax, 1
    jnz     oddCluster

evenCluster:
    and     dx, 0b0000111111111111
    jmp     next

oddCluster:
    shr     dx, 4

next:
    mov     word [cluster], dx
    cmp     dx, 0x0ff0
    jb      loadFile

    jmp     0x0050:0 ; Far jmp to KRNLDR.SYS

failure:
    mov     si, fail
    call    printMsg

    mov     si, anykey
    call    printMsg

    mov     ah, 0x00
    int     0x16 ; Await key press

    jmp     0xffff:0 ; Reboot with far jmp to BIOS

stage2:         db          "KRNLDR  SYS"
fail:           db          "Operating system not found", 0xd, 0xa, 0x0
anykey:         db          "Press any key to reboot", 0xd, 0xa, 0x0

cluster:        dw          0

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

What can I do?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you considered using something like BOCHs to step through your code with its debugger? BOCHs has a built in debugger that works well in real mode. You can watch your code and see how it fails.

Comment: I just set it up. Now I'm debugging

Answer (score 2):

```
loadFat:
    mov     dx, [di + 26] ; Starting address of entry
    xor     ax, ax
    mov     al, byte [bpbNumberOfFATs]
    mul     word [bpbSectorsPerFAT] ; Number of sectors used by the FATs

    mov     word [cluster], dx
```

One issue here is that `mul` with a word operand multiplies that word by `ax` and leaves the result in the register pair `dx:ax`. So you overwrite `dx` with a zero before using it to initialise the variable named cluster. When converting that FAT entry index to a sector number, subtracting 2 from zero results in a very high sector number.

Which brings us to the second issue I spotted. Usually, the zero in [cluster] should have 2 subtracted from it, the result of that multiplied by 1 (amount sectors per cluster), and then the "first data sector" added, which would result in a very low number again, which would cause a failure but likely differ somewhat. However, your clusterToLba doesn't actually convert to the LBA starting sector for that cluster's data, because it doesn't add in the "first data sector" (ie, LBA number of the first sector of the first cluster). This needs to be computed by your loader. It is the starting sector of the root directory plus the amount of root directory sectors.